# No quantifier on bounded variable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is how subset is defined in set theory:
$A \subseteq B \iff \forall x \in A \implies x \in B$.

So, for how many elements this $x$ without quantifier in $x \in B$ actually stands for? All or some (at least one, maybe all)?

Isn't $\exists x \in B$ what actually is assumed?

Comment: It is $(\forall x)(x\in A\implies x\in B)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quantifier is over the whole implication, so $A \subseteq B$ means:

$$\forall x: (x \in A \implies x \in B)$$

Comment: No it means, whatever set $x$ you take, if you know $x$ is in $A$, you can conclude $x$ is in $B$ as well.@Vuk

Comment: So $\forall x$ part in your answer means for all objects of $A \subseteq B$?

Comment: No @Vuk for all $x$ in the "universe"... $A \subseteq B$ is just a shorthand for the formula I gave. It's not an "object".

Comment: Universe = all possible elements?

Comment: @Vuk yes, indeed. But to prove $A \subseteq B$ in practice, you can start by taking an element of $A$ (if it exists). If $x \notin A$, then $x \in A \implies x \in B$ is already true (false antecedent), so there is nothing to prove in that case. This is why $\emptyset \subseteq B$ is always true.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, $x$ is not a set (in general).

Comment: @md2perpe In set theory, everything is a set.

Comment: @md2perpe Or are you working in set theory with Urelements? This is quite uncommon.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, indeed, but normally you don't think of the numbers as sets. And I don't think that Vuk is on that deep level of set theory.

Comment: @md2perpe  numbers *are*  special sets. $\forall x$ quantifies over everything that can be an element of a set. It's clear from the context.